# React Deployment: package.json file's "homepage" property not being recognized by build script

Tags: reactjs, cpanel, web-deployment

I am attempting to deploy my react website to a webhost and continue to run into problems in the deployment process.

I've added the domain URL I purchased to the package.json file as:

```
"homepage": "http://louisericketts.com/",
```

after I use the "npm run build" script the console tells me this:

[image]

When I navigate into the build folder that react creates and check the manifest.json file I see:

```
"start_url": ".",
```

Is this common behavior? I'm teaching myself React and this is my first experience deploying.

I've uploaded the contents of the build folder to the hosting server, but the website isn't displaying. It just shows me a placeholder from the hosting company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a file to the root of my project file called .env and placed this line of code in it:

```
PUBLIC_URL=http://www.louisericketts.com/
```

Ran npm run build and the script recognized the homepage property on my package.json file.

[image]